# I cannot iterate on insert statement using end of month date as a parameter

Tags: sql, loops, iteration, recursive-query

I'm trying iterate in a loop which will insert on monthly basis a number of 'active' records for a specific end of month date given as a parameter on the python function. A several transformation and joins will be done using several tables and as a result we have a table which holds records on end of month snapshot level, for example the target table would look like:

**trg_table**:

| sanpshot_date | prod_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | 1123 | 45.56 |
| 2020-01-31 | 1125 | 43.32 |
| 2020-01-31 | 1163 | 12.54 |
| 2020-02-29 | 1123 | 45.58 |
| 2020-02-29 | 1125 | 44.32 |
| 2020-02-29 | 1163 | 11.98 |
| ... | ... | ... |

if we group and count the records at the end they should look like:
**trg_table**:

| sanpshot_date | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | 45,556 |
| 2020-02-29 | 49,980 |
| 2020-03-31 | 41,558 |
| 2020-04-30 | 48,569 |
| 2020-05-31 | 47,987 |
| ... | ... |

the way how the sql codes is build and insert records only for one month is:

```sql
create table trg_table
with 
temp_tbl1 as ( select .... from table x1 where p_date is between date_start and date_end ),
temp_tbl2 as 
( select ... from table x2 join  temp_tbl1  on x2.prod_id = temp_tbl1.prod_id
 where p_date is between x2.date_start and x2.date_end ),
temp_tbl3 as 
( select ... from table x3 
   join temp_tbl2  on x3.prod_id = temp_tbl2.prod_id
where p_date is between date_start and date_end 
)
select * from temp_tbl3  
                join trg_table on temp_tbl3.prod_id = trg_table.prod_id
                                and   temp_tbl3.snapshot_date=trg_table.snapshot_date-1 
/* this check the records recursively from previous month for any change in the price or smth */
```

where p_date is end of month date given as a paramete in the bigening.

This is fine when we run for only one snapshot_date (ex. 2020-01-31) but we want to pass this parameter on a loop and execute several months on one shot.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Adk.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Rolled back the replacement of text by images - images of code or data can not be copy/pasted and are bad. The tables are fine.

Comment: I'm a little lost on what you are asking.  The question starts with two different possible result tables, both with multiple months.  Then it shows complicated SQL, and makes the statement that the code only works for one month.  There is also no database tag.  This is very confusing.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff,

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff,
Thnx a lot for commenting on this topic.
I will try to explain once more what I'm trying to reach with my code.
The problem is that I want to build a history of the product (from 2009 to 2021) which is result of combination of some dimension and transactional tables. 
The code should cover two issues:
1. Executing steps one by one for each end of month from Oct 2009 to May 2021
2. Checking recursively previous month for the status of a column on its table.

The way it is working now, I'm executing it month by month.
Pls let me know if it is clear enough.
Br, Agron